# Do a dual sliding panel with Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm currently trying to do a "landing page" for an Ionic (v2) app with a dual choice pannel from this codepen : https://codepen.io/ettrics/pen/ogrgOy
I just pasted the code of the HTML and the CSS, and i put the JS inside script divs in my index (I know it's not the right way but it's just the time of trying)
Here is the code of the HomePage component :
`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

}
```

When i do an `ionic serve` the visual is here but the Panels are not showing and on lauch my JS console says : 
`Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator`

I have this message even when I add cordova.js..

What part am I missing ? Or is there a best way to do that ?

Thank you in advance for any help !

Comment: Answering second part of the code.. cordova is not available in browser and that warning has nothing to do with your codepen code. check whether you copy-pasted the code in correct places or not.